# Why does gsub's '\1' capture group produce this string?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I am confused as to why I am capturing this pattern via '\1' grouping. I am capturing two digits at a time, but why does it skip here:

```
"123 456 789".gsub(/(\d)(\d)/, '\1')
=> "13 46 79"
```

I can understand that '\0' gives me the original string:

```
"123 456 789".gsub(/(\d)(\d)/, '\0')
=> "123 456 789"
```

This also confuses me, but I can understand '\2' once I learn what '\1' is doing:

```
"123 456 789".gsub(/(\d)(\d)/, '\2')
=> "23 56 89"
```

Comment: What is your expected output when using the \1?

Comment: @DylanMarkow  "12 45 78"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex matches `"12"`, `"45"`, `"78"`, and `gsub` replaces them with `"1"`, `"4"`, `"7"`, respectively, giving `"13 46 79"`.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain `12 45 78`, you need to use

```
(\d)\d\b
```

And replace with `\1`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA0hK7/2)

Here, we match a digit and capture it (`(\d)`), then we match another digit (with `\d`) that is right before a word boundary `\b`.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/0811IV):

```
puts "123 456 789".gsub(/(\d)\d\b/, '\1')
```